# Acumatica - Modify APPayment table to contain User-Entered String for ACH

Tags: acumatica, banking

After consulting on the Acumatica forums, I have been instructed that the tables which are available for ACH coding are restricted so that each entry is technically unique. But, the field I wish to display in the ACH lines is what we use in a Reference Number field (not necessarily unique, but the way we use it IS actually unique). While I can't join to the tables that would hold the data I want, is it possible to create a custom data field/attribute in APPayments (or one of the other tables that feeds the ACH coding forms) which I can then enter the Vendor Reference Number in order to pass it to the ACH code?

Answer (score 1):

In ACH files, you only have a few fields to put custom data in.  The Identification Number is very common to put a reference number into.  It's 15 characters long.  Sometimes you have available the Entry Descriptor as well to set.  ACH format also allows for an addenda record as free text.

These are in the actual NACHA format, so they should be supported by any vendor that takes ACH payments.  If they show up in the file, they should be in the database as a field to join on.